# facebook login development mode refused to display

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm in development mode. The link I'm using to login into facebook is already using `_top` as target

Here is the error:

> Refused to display
>   'https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=299414960683257&domain=localhost&origin=1&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D43%23cb%3Df6b24dd350a5c%26domain%3Dlocalhost%26origin%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%252Ff1a8662460963a%26relation%3Dparent&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&sdk=joey'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

I had same error in a previous project and I resolved just using `_top` as target. Another important detail is that I've no error if the user is already logged in facebook. So the error is shown only when the login procedure try to show login page, the same doesn't happens on first access when the user have to allow permissions required by the app.

As I understood in development mode only app's developers, testers and administrators can login. But I can't find anywhere that the user must be already logged in when click on login button. May this error disappear when the app switch in live mode or there could be other problems?

Comment: That’s quite a common error, but not necessarily something to worry about, unless it actually prevents your app from working …?

Comment: Prevent my app from working. It could be strange for the user to go to facebook, log in there, come back to my website and re try to login via facebook.

Comment: How exactly, what is going wrong and where? Show us what you are actually doing.